# Confused about the ASRock BIOS update instructions, is it safe to upgrade my BIOS?

Tags: bios, motherboard

What does this message mean?

> * User will not able to flash to previous BIOS once upgrading to this BIOS version.
>
> ** We don't recommend users to update the BIOS if their system is already running normally.

Is it safe to upgrade my BIOS or might I completely toast my motherboard?

I need to upgrade to use Windows 11 and secure boot.

It's for a Z370 Pro4 and link is on [this official ASRock page](https://www.asrock.com/mb/Intel/Z370%20Pro4/index.asp#BIOS).

[image]

Comment: Why do you believe those warnings would “toast” your motherboard? Those are boilerplate warnings. “User will not able to flash to previous BIOS once upgrading to this BIOS version.” So that means you upgrade your BIOS and that is that. You cannot downgrade. “We don't recommend users to update the BIOS if their system is already running normally.” That is just a general, “If it ain’t broke, don’t fix it…” warning. If you want to upgrade to Windows 11 and you can’t with your current BIOS then that is something that needs to be fixed up updating the BIOS.

Comment: But they say it's irreversible, so what if something goes wrong? Can I put back the prior older BIOS version I got from the download?

Comment: Why do you think that a BIOS update from 2019 will let you install Windows 11?

Comment: Because that's what some people said on Reddit

Comment: Updating a BIOS to support an OS isn't super uncommon, and I've never had an unrecoverable error updating my BIOS. I also update BIOS even when there isn't a significant problem with the computer. For context, I'm a long time IT veteran and I've updated thousands of computer BIOS'. They're trying to cover their butts. Just follow the instructions and update the BIOS. Whether it solves the underlying problem or not, it is very UNLIKELY to cause any problems.

Comment: https://superuser.com/users/74026/music2myear I want to choose you for the answer, can you reply with answer and not a comment? music2myear